# django annotate count filter

Tags: django, django-queryset, annotate

I am trying to count daily records for some model, but I would like the count was made only for records with some fk field = xy so I get list with days where there was a new record created but some may return 0.

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    place = models.ForeignKey(Place)
    note = models.TextField()
    time_added = models.DateTimeField()
```

Say There's a Place with name="NewYork"

```
data = SomeModel.objects.extra({'created': "date(time_added)"}).values('created').annotate(placed_in_ny_count=Count('id'))
```

This works, but shows all records.. all places.

Tried with filtering, but it does not return days, where there was no record with `place.name="NewYork"`. That's not what I need.

Comment: Can you show the code with filtering, show the output, and say what you think is wrong with it?

Comment: @GarethRees `data = SomeModel.objects.extra({'created': "date(time_added)"}).values('created').annotate(placed_in_ny_count=Count('id'))` `len(data)` gives 153. Adding `.filter(place=Place.objects.get(name='NewYork'))` returns less as it only returns days when SomeModel record with the 'place' was created. I want days without such records returned too. I would like to do something like `ny_counts=Count('id' where place=Place.objects.get(name='NewYork'))` and get `[{'placed_in_ny_count': 23, 'created': datetime.date(2012,1,12)}, {'placed_in_ny_count': 0, 'created': datetimedate(2012,1,13)}...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you want to know, for each day on which *any* object was added, how many of the objects created on that day have a place whose name is New York. (Let me know if I've misunderstood.) In SQL that needs an [outer join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_joins):

```sql
SELECT m.id, date(m.time_added) AS created, count(p.id) AS count
  FROM myapp_somemodel AS m
  LEFT OUTER JOIN myapp_place AS p
       ON m.place_id = p.id
       AND p.name = 'New York'
  GROUP BY created
```

So you can always express this in Django using a [raw SQL query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/sql/):

```python
for o in SomeModel.objects.raw('SELECT ...'):   # query as above
    print 'On {0}, {1} objects were added in New York'.format(o.created, o.count)
```

Notes:

1. I haven't tried to work out if this is expressible in Django's query language; it may be, but [as the developers say](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/misc/design-philosophies/#option-to-drop-into-raw-sql-easily-when-needed), the database API is "a shortcut but not necessarily an end-all-be-all.")
2. The `m.id` is superfluous in the SQL query, but [Django requires](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/sql/#deferring-model-fields) that "the primary key ... must always be included in a raw query".
3. You probably don't want to write the literal `'New York'` into your query, so [pass a parameter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw) instead: `raw('SELECT ... AND p.name = %s ...', [placename])`.